Derive memory limit in kubernetes config
I am completely new to Kubernetes. I have this values.yaml file which has kubernetes configuration for the taskmanager and jobmanager in it. I am trying to derive the value for memory.limit property for both jobmanager and taskmanager using the other properties like process size, heap size, overhead, etc. I don't what properties to add up and eliminate to arrive at a number for the memory limit.
I would like to know how to calculate the value for this taskmanager.memory.limit property and in what possible values can I derive the value instead of hardcoding it using other memory specific attributes. Any references to this property to it will be helpful. Thanks in advance!
Here is a part of the configuration that includes the config for taskmanager and job:
jobmanager:
  ports:
    rpc: 6123
    blobServer: 6124
    webui: 8081
    protectedWebUI: 8080
  livenessProbe:
    tcpSocket:
      port: 6123
    initialDelaySeconds: 90
    periodSeconds: 60
  readinessProbe:
    tcpSocket:
      port: 6123
    initialDelaySeconds: 5
    periodSeconds: 60
  memory: # in Mb
    processSize: 1024
    limit: 1024
    jvmOverheadMin: 64
    jvmOverheadMax: 512
    heapSize: 512
  replicas: 1
  cpu: 1
  #Should be overrided on values.yaml or by parameters to the corresponding class from your job
  jobId: ~
  className: ~

taskmanager:
  ports:
    rpc: 6122
    queryState: 6125
  replicaCount: 2
  taskSlots: 1
  parallelismDefault: 10
  livenessProbe:
    initialDelaySeconds: 30
    periodSeconds: 60
  memory: # in Mb
    processSize: 32768
    limit: 16384
    heapSize: 8192
    offheapSize: 4096
    jvmOverheadMin: 512
    jvmOverheadMax: 11264    
    flinkSize: 21672  
  replicas: 1
  cpu: 1
  autoscaling:
    enabled: false
    # metric: cpu
    # target: 40
    # min: 1
    # max: 1
    # scaleUpPolicies:
      # pods: 4
      # periodSeconds: 30

# either LOAD_FROM_LAST_SAVEPOINT or NO_SAVEPOINT
savepoint: NO_SAVEPOINT
env: ~
flinkService: nexus-flink
local: false # override to true for local env cluster. in order to create role and role binding for the default account
serviceAccount:
  # false to use default account, if true will create an account with releaseName as name by default or the name specified
  create: false
  name: "" # empty means default
ingress:
  ports:
    http: 80

